# SQL: combining two sql queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, outer-join

I have two tables:

```
T_CHAMBRE_CHB (CHB_NUM); 

T_PLANNING_PLN (PLN_JOUR ,CHB_NUM, PLN_LIBRE);
```

I have these values in it:

T_CHAMBRE_CHB:

```
1
2
3
4
```

T_PLANNIG_CHB:

```
1   2000-01-12  1   False
2   2000-01-12  2   False
3   2000-01-13  1   False
4   2000-01-13  2   False
5   2000-01-13  4   True
```

I would like to get the rooms occpation the 13 janvier 2000 for information if a room is not in the planning (here 3) that's mean it's free, so the result should be:

```
CHB_NUM     PLN_LIBRE 
----------- --------- 
1           False
2           False
3           True 
4           True
```

I have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TCC.CHB_NUM, TPP.PLN_LIBRE
FROM T_CHAMBRE_CHB AS TCC,
     T_PLANNING_PLN AS TPP
WHERE TCC.CHB_NUM=TPP.CHB_NUM AND TPP.PLN_JOUR  = '2000-01-13'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT TCC.CHB_NUM, TPP.PLN_LIBRE
FROM T_CHAMBRE_CHB AS TCC,
     T_PLANNING_PLN AS TPP
WHERE TCC.CHB_NUM NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT (TPP2.CHB_NUM) FROM T_PLANNING_PLN AS TPP2);
```

I get this result:

```
1   1   False
2   2   False
3   3   False
4   3   True 
5   4   True
```

I don't know why I get the third line ( 3---->False )

I think I should use an OUTER UNION but SQL Server doesn't like the syntax.

Comment: No need for `SELECT DISTINCT` when `UNION`, since `UNION` will remove duplicate rows. No need for `SELECT DISTINCT` when `[NOT] IN` (sub-query.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below query might give the required result :-

```
declare @date as date='2000-01-13'

select distinct TCC.CHB_NUM,COALESCE(TPP.PLN_JOUR,@date) PLN_JOUR,COALESCE(TPP.PLN_LIBRE,'True') PLN_LIBRE    
from T_CHAMBRE_CHB TCC
LEFT OUTER JOIN
T_PLANNING_PLN TPP ON TCC.CHB_NUM=TPP.CHB_NUM
WHERE TPP.PLN_JOUR=@date OR TPP.PLN_JOUR IS NULL
```

Output :-

```
 CHB_NUM    PLN_JOUR    PLN_LIBRE
    1      2000-01-13   False
    2      2000-01-13   False
    3      2000-01-13   True
    4      2000-01-13   True
```

Comment: So there is no way to do it without tsql , just pur sql ?

Comment: `select TCC.CHB_NUM,COALESCE(TPP.PLN_JOUR,'2000-01-13') PLN_JOUR,COALESCE(TPP.PLN_LIBRE,'True') PLN_LIBRE    
from T_CHAMBRE_CHB TCC
LEFT OUTER JOIN
T_PLANNING_PLN TPP ON TCC.CHB_NUM=TPP.CHB_NUM
WHERE TPP.PLN_JOUR='2000-01-13' OR TPP.PLN_JOUR IS NULL;` ?!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use left join if I am understanding your question.

Please use below query may be it helps you

```
SELECT T_CHAMBRE_CHB.CHB_NUM, ISNULL(T_PLANNIG_CHB.PLN_LIBRE, FALSE)
FROM T_CHAMBRE_CHB
LEFT JOIN T_PLANNIG_CHB ON (T_CHAMBRE_CHB.CHB_NUM = T_PLANNIG_CHB.CHB_NUM)
WHERE T_PLANNIG_CHB.PLN_JOUR = '2000-01-13'
```

Comment: sorry 3---> true ... not False, but your query returns 12 column.. with  two times all to true and one time all to false..

Comment: It's what i have posted, but the result of your query is multuplicating rows

Comment: What you have posted is not the full data. Usefull information would be the DDL of your tables and the used version of your database...

Comment: Try now I have added distinct to it